# IIS returns 403.14 error if a physical path corresponds to url

Tags: iis, routes, handler

Is there a way to override IIS and tell it to always let handler handle requests? At the moment if, for example, "path" is an existing folder in root, url is "http://domain.com/path" and there is no "default" document in folder, IIS will return a 403, even if that path is defined in my custom handler. I can't think of anything other than leaving default.aspx in folder with redirection (or content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, found the answer accidentally while looking for something unrelated. RouteCollection object has a property RouteExistingFiles, which defaults to false, but if set to true explicitly will exhibit the required behaviour.

Unfortunately that also means that all files will need to get routed, including css and images, so extra handling would need to be implemented.